# ionic generate translation files from the src

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, translation, ngx-translate

WordPress can detect all the strings that needs to be translated. I want to know if there is something similar in Ionic.

Something that goes through the source code and gets all the strings marked as translatable, like:
`{{ 'String to translate' | translate }}`

Preferably not only in the HMTL files like the example above, but also in the .js and .ts files too.

Or if anyone has a process of managing all translations, would be helpful too.

Comment: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core